# error with reference value in getDetails - google places search

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The following is my code. I would like to get all details of a place like formatted address etc in the form of a list. But I am getting error with getDetails() and reference. I would be very grateful if anyone can tell me where my error is

```
    var map, placesList;

    function initialize() {
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 17
        });

        var request = {
            location: pyrmont,
            radius: 500,
            types: ['store']
        };


        placesList = document.getElementById('places');

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


        var request1 = {

            reference: 'CnRkAAAAGnBVNFDeQoOQHzgdOpOqJNV7K9-c5IQrWFUYD9TNhUmz5-aHhfqyKH0zmAcUlkqVCrpaKcV8ZjGQKzB6GXxtzUYcP-muHafGsmW-1CwjTPBCmK43AZpAwW0FRtQDQADj3H2bzwwHVIXlQAiccm7r4xIQmjt_Oqm2FejWpBxLWs3L_RoUbharABi5FMnKnzmRL2TGju6UA4k'

        };
        service.getDetails(request1, createMarkers);
    }

    function callback(results, status, pagination) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            return;
        } else {
            createMarkers(results);

            if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
                var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
                moreButton.disabled = false;
                google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(moreButton, 'click',

                    function () {
                        moreButton.disabled = true;
                        pagination.nextPage();
                    });
            }
        }
    }
    function createMarkers(places, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                var image = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                });

                placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '<br>' + place.formatted_address + '</li>';

                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `for loop` to iterate over `places`in function `createMarkers` but there is just object:

```
Object {
    address_components: Array[6], 
    formatted_address: "5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont NSW, Australia",
    formatted_phone_number: "(02) 9374 4000", 
    geometry: Object, 
    icon: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png"…}
```

without array properties. I've just removed `for loop` which was around your code and got the address in the list and proper zoom to that address.

You asked for just one specific service. See docs:

*In addition to providing a list of Places within an area, the Places service can also return detailed information about a specific Place. Once a Place has been returned in a Place Search response, its reference property can be used to request additional details about that Place, such as its complete address, phone number, user rating and reviews, etc*

```
function createMarkers(place, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        //for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

            var image = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '<br>' + place.formatted_address + '</li>';

            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        //}
    }
}
```

And change `callback` to something like this:

```
function callback(results, status, pagination) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        return;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var markerPlace = results[i];
            createMarkers(markerPlace, status);
        }
        ...
```

You are handling different object with same function `createMarker()`. So you get `undefined` for `formatted_address` for some of the results. In those cases you can use `vicinity` property:

```
            placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '<br>' +
                (place.formatted_address ? place.formatted_address : place.vicinity)  
                + '</li>';
```